# Нужна ли запятая в заголовке?

Tags: пунктуация

Мечты какие они есть

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, у нас нет тега "запятая", а есть "пунктуация" (потрудитесь посмотреть другие вопросы). Во-вторых, цитируемое предложение берется в кавычки (а уж о "спасибо" и "пожалуйста" я даже не заикаюсь). В-третьих, невозможно понять смысл предложения, потому что Вы не потрудились поставить в конце знак препинания (или Вы этого в школе еще не проходили?).
Так вот. Если в конце должна стоять точка, то предложение сформулировано криво. Правильнее сказать "Мечты, как они есть", и тут нужна запятая. Впрочем, если в конце должен стоять вопросительный знак, то запятая тоже будет: "Мечты, какие они есть?"

Comment: Прошу прощения за резкость, но кромешная безграмотность и невоспитанность школьников и не только просто убивает уже.